# Remove rows from a panda dataframe with unsorted index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is how my data looks:

```
print(len(y_train),len(index_1))
index_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=index_1)
print("y_train: ")
print(y_train)
print("index_1: ")
print(index_1)
```

Output:

```
1348 555
y_train: 
1677    1
1519    0
1114    0
690     1
1012    1
       ..
1893    1
1844    0
1027    1
1649    1
1789    1
Name: Team 1 Win, Length: 1348, dtype: int64
index_1: 
        0
0       0
1       2
2       6
3       7
4       8
..    ...
550  1335
551  1341
552  1342
553  1344
554  1346
```

I want to remove a number of rows (index_1) from a panda dataframe (y_train). So the values in the index_1 df are the rows I want to remove. Problem is that the dataframe is not in order, so when index_1's first item is 0, I want it to remove the first row in y_train (i.e. index 1677), instead of the row with index 0.
This is my attempt:

```
y_train_short = y_train.drop(index_1)
```

This is what I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-49f2cce7bac0> in <module>
     22 print(index_1)
     23 print(index_1)
---> 24 y_train_short = y_train.drop(index_1)
     25 
     26 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   4137             level=level,
   4138             inplace=inplace,
-> 4139             errors=errors,
   4140         )
   4141 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   3934         for axis, labels in axes.items():
   3935             if labels is not None:
-> 3936                 obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
   3937 
   3938         if inplace:

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _drop_axis(self, labels, axis, level, errors)
   3968                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level, errors=errors)
   3969             else:
-> 3970                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
   3971             result = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   3972 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   5016         if mask.any():
   5017             if errors != "ignore":
-> 5018                 raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
   5019             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   5020         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: '[0] not found in axis'
```

Independently of the fact that index 0 doesn't exist in y_train, I imagine that if it did, it would not do what I want it to do. So how do I remove the right rows from this dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `y_train.iloc[index_1[0]]` retrieves rows from *y_train*
taking indicated integer positions.

When you run `y_train.iloc[index_1[0]].index`, you will get
**indices** of these rows.

So do drop these rows, you can run:

```
y_train.drop(y_train.iloc[index_1[0]].index, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) on index:

```
# set index to start from 0
y_train = y_train.reset_index(drop=True)

# do simple filter
y_train = y_train[~y_train.index.isin(index_1[0])].copy()
```